# Applications are not loaded into OS 7 simulators

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I cannot get my applications loaded in OS 7 simulators. I am using BlackBerry Java Plug-In for Eclipse 1.3.0 and downloaded the BlackBerry JRE 7.0.0. I tried `Run As -> BlackBerry Simulator`, but the application was not loaded in the simulator. Moreover, although I had installed many OS 7 simulators, they are not listed in the Devices drop-down box of the `Run Configurations -> Simulator tab`. I tried to load the application manually into the simulator, but I could not manage it either. The deliverable - > Standard - > 7.0 folder contains a `.cod` file and many `.debug` files. I tried the `.cod` file, but it did not show up in the simulator.

Then I downloaded the BlackBerry Java Plug-In for Eclipse 1.5.0, but there still are no applications in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

first -  in order to run a specific simulator go into *debug configurations* or *run configurations* and under the *simulator* tab, *Device* drop down, you should be able to select your simulators.

second - in the application descriptor do you have the "Do not display the application icon on the home screen" checked?

Comment: Thank you Tamar, but it turned out that I had too many image files in res folder. Removing some them solved the issue.

Also, re-installing the simulators into the directory where the older simulators reside made them visible in Eclipse plug-in.